# Express the following in terms of $\phi$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**1.** Express $\phi (n^k) $ in terms of n and $\phi(n)$. I know the result is supposed to be $ n^{k-1} \phi(n)$ and I was thinking of approaching it by induction but I am not quite sure.

**2.** Given $ m \ge 2$, express $\sum_{1<k<m,(k,m)=1} k$ in terms of *m* and $\phi(m)$.

I believe the result is supposed to be $ m \phi(m)/2$.

Comment: I think you want $1 \le k$ instead of $1 < k$ in your summation for $(1/2)m\phi(m)$ to be the result.

Comment: You should probably say what $\phi$ is. If it is the Euler's totient function, you should use ([tag:totient-function]) tag.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, you should write out $n$ as a product of prime powers.  The function $\phi$ is nice to express when you have such a decomposition.  I don't think induction will necessarily be helpful.

For the second, there is a simplifying trick of grouping the terms into pairs of the form $\{k, m-k\}$.

Comment: For the first one, you now derive the corresponding expansion for $n^k$ and apply $\phi$ to it.  For the second, note that if you pair terms this way that each pair sums to $m$.

Comment: Your sum should be a product, but other than that it looks to me that you have something that is $n^{k-1}$ times $n\Pi_{p\mid n}(1-1/p)$.  For the second, count the number of pairs and then multiply by $m/2$ to get the sum.

Comment: Yeah you are right it is supposed to be a product. I got what you meant but it seems simple. That is all I have to do, right ? $n^{k-1} $ and $\phi(n)$ which is the other part. @ RoldHoyer   As for the second one I would be really grateful if you were more explicit.

Comment: I still don't have a clear idea for the 2nd one. I would be really grateful if you expanded it more. @RolfHoyer

Comment: There are $\phi(m)/2$ pairs, each pair adds to $m$, so the total sum is $m\phi(m)/2$.

Comment: I am sorry but why $\phi(m)$/2 pairs. @RolfHoyer

Comment: the number of $k<m$ with $(k,m)=1$ is $\phi(m)$.  The number of pairs is half the number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

For any integer $n$:

$\phi (2^n) = 2^{n-1}$

and

$\phi (b^n) = (b-1)b^{n-1}$, if $b$ is prime.

Proof:

$\phi (b) = b-1$ if $b$ is prime,

$\phi (b^n) = \phi (b)b^{n-1}$